How to explain the concept of "body" as in "rupakaya" in intuitive terms?
I am looking at Rupakaya on the Rigpa Wiki, and it says:

[It] refers to the two 'form kayas' of a buddha: nirmanakaya and sambhogakaya. It is said that the rupakaya arises from the accumulation of merit and the dharmakaya from the accumulation of wisdom.

Using the term "body" confuses me, like the Dharmakaya, the "Absolute or Truth Body". How can truth have a body? Can you explain how this works in an intuitive way?

In the early buddhist teachings,
While it's true kāya means collection, by default when the buddha uses 'kāya' alone, unqualified, it's referring to the rūpa-kāya (physical body) of the person, not a nāma-kaya (mental collection) or any other kind of colleciton. See MN 119 for example (all meditations that require a physical body). And the vinaya, and the numerous passages related to basic sense restraint, make a clear distinction between offenses that use kāya (physical body), vāca (vocalized speech with sound), mano (mental activity).

I believe that the concepts of Dharmakaya (eternal truth form) and Nirmanakaya (physical form) originated from the following sutta quote.
The Buddha downplayed the importance of his physical form and advised Ven. Vakkali to focus on the teachings, stating that when one sees the Buddha, one sees the Dharma (teachings), and when one sees the Dharma, one sees the Buddha.
In other words, the Dharma is what the Buddha stands for, and the Dharma is what the Buddha represents. The Dharma (teachings) is his eternal "form".

Vakkali: “For a long time, venerable sir, I have wanted to come to see
the Blessed One, but I haven’t been fit enough to do so.”
Buddha: “Enough, Vakkali! Why do you want to see this foul body?  One
who sees the Dhamma (teachings) sees me; one who sees me sees the
Dhamma (teachings). For in seeing the Dhamma (teachings), Vakkali, one
sees me; and in seeing me, one sees the Dhamma (teachings).
SN 22.87

I believe that the concept where the Nirmanakayas of all the past Buddhas emanate from one Dharmakaya originates from the following sutta quote.
It simply means that all the past and future Buddhas rediscover, understand and teach the same Dharma (teachings), because it is the natural law.
Hence their physical appearance as teachers, emanate from the Dharma (teachings) as their one eternal "form". In other words, all the Buddhas stand for the same Dharma (teachings) and all the Buddhas represent the same Dharma (teachings).

Past Buddhas,
future Buddhas,
& he who is the Buddha now,
removing the sorrow of many —
all have dwelt,
will dwell, he dwells,
revering the true Dhamma.
This, for Buddhas, is a natural law.
Therefore one who desires his own good,
aspiring for greatness,
should respect the true Dhamma,
recollecting the Buddhas' Teaching.
SN 6.2

And what about the Sambhogakaya (enjoyment/ reward form, or perhaps inspirational form)?
I speculate that it's related to the following quote.
When one recollects the Buddha, who he was, what he achieved, what he contributed and what he stood for, that person becomes inspired and his fears dispelled. So, this inspirational mental image of the Buddha is the Buddha's inspirational "form". He can manifest in this "form" to inspire and dispel fear.

But bhikkhus, I say this: If you have gone to a forest or to the foot
of a tree or to an empty hut, and fear or trepidation or terror should
arise in you, on that occasion you should recollect me thus: ‘The
Blessed One is an arahant, perfectly enlightened, accomplished in true
knowledge and conduct, fortunate, knower of the world, unsurpassed
leader of persons to be tamed, teacher of devas and humans, the
Enlightened One, the Blessed One.’ For when you recollect me,
bhikkhus, whatever fear or trepidation or terror you may have will be
abandoned.
SN 11.3

When it comes to Mahayana Buddhism, I take some of the teachings as giving a poetic twist to the staid teachings of the Pali Canon.

While your question is Mahayana, the word "kaya" in the older Pali teachings does not mean "physical body". The word "kaya" means "group" or "collection", such as when the various sutta collections are called "Nikaya". For example, in the Pali suttas, the word "kaya" is used to refer to:

Group of mental phenomena or nama-kaya (DN 15).

Group of physical phenomena or rupa-kaya (DN 15).

The breathing as a kaya among other kaya (MN 118).


Therefore, in the question, a "kaya" or "collection" is indicated by the term "accumulation".
The "accumulation" of merit and "accumulation" of wisdom are the "collection" of a Buddha. Thus they are the mental "body" of the Buddha; which also pervades a Buddha's physical "body". For example, a Buddha's physical body is rendered "harmless" & "gracious" due to the accumulation of merit & wisdom. Thus the entirety of the "group" of a Buddha's mental & physical faculties are made up of a Buddha's "accumulation" of merit and "accumulation" of wisdom.
The Dhammapada contains this excellent quote which may be helpful:


Think not lightly of good, saying, "It will not come to me." Drop by drop is the water pot filled. Likewise, the wise man, gathering it
little by little, fills himself with good.


Its like a piggy bank full of money. Money is accumulated and deposited in the piggy bank until the piggy bank is full. The piggy bank represents the "collection" or "body" of "accumulations".

